# React tic-tac-toe tutorial enhancement for two loops

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm stuck on the tic-tac-toe tutorial enhancement, and wonder why the following code using a `renderBoard()` function that crashes. Also, I'm using codepen in the browser, and the run-time stack dump doesn't seem to provide any useful information other than where the problem occurs - any suggestions appreciated.

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  renderRow(row) {
    return (
      <div className="board-row">
        {this.renderSquare(row * 3 + 0)}
        {this.renderSquare(row * 3 + 1)}
        {this.renderSquare(row * 3 + 2)}
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderBoard() {
    const rows = [];
    for (row=0; row<3; row++)
      {
        rows.push(this.renderRow(row));
      }
    return ({rows});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderBoard()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Need more info. How are you calling this? Might as well show us the codepen.

Comment: OK - working on that... I'm new to codepen and trying to figure out how to make it 'save' the correct version of the code... and how to work around codepen seeming to stop updating when I make code changes... very frustrating.

Comment: I prefer Stackblitz for React fiddles, but whatever works :-)

Comment: Here's hopefully a link to the codepen... https://codepen.io/cleeharris/pen/gVBpyb

See lines 58-61 of the JSX.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with that code.

```
  renderBoard() {
    const rows = [];
    for (row=0; row<3; row++) // <--- (1) You haven't declared `row`. Put the word `let` in front to declare it
      {
        rows.push(this.renderRow(row));
      }
    return ({rows}); // <--- (2) You're returning an object with 1 property called rows. You should just be returning the array as-is.
  }
```

And (3) When rendering arrays, you have to add a `key`.

```
  renderRow(row) {
    return (
      <div key={row} className="board-row">
        {this.renderSquare(row * 3 + 0)}
        {this.renderSquare(row * 3 + 1)}
        {this.renderSquare(row * 3 + 2)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here's a fixed version: https://codepen.io/mnpenner/pen/dxgzop

Answer (score 0):

@mpen has already mentioned the problems with your code itself currently.

Though I will answer the question that was originally asked which is in regards to using two loops to create the enhancement as your code itself is only using one loop rather than two.

I'm currently just passing size as a parameter for flexibility (so that if you want to change the size of the for loop in the future to create a 5x5 tic-tac-toe, it's easily adjustable).

Note: I believe the author is following this tutorial:
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

```
class Board extends React.Component {

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square 
        key={i}
        value={this.props.squares[i]} 
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  renderBoard(size) {
    const board = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      let row = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        row.push(this.renderSquare(i * size + j));
      }
      board.push(
        <div key={i} className="board-row">
          {row}
        </div>
      )
    }
    return board;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderBoard(3)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write a function `renderRow`. Here is how I did it:

```
let board = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      row.push(<Square value={squares[i*3+j]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(i*3+j)} />);
    }
    board.push(<div className="board-row">{row}</div>);
}
return(
  <>
    <div className="status">{status}</div>
    {board}
  </>;
);
```

Comment: using loops and imperative programming is against react philosophy

Comment: @Alex perhaps you should file an issue to react.dev to make their tutorial clearer since they say "2. Rewrite Board to use two loops to make the squares instead of hardcoding them."